# Javascript continue statement in while loop causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop, continue

I'm trying to create a `while` loop with a continue statement. However it seems to be causing an infinite loop and I can't figure out why.

The code below to me seems like it should start with the `var tasksToDo` at 3 then decrement down to 0 skipping number 2 on the way.

```
var tasksToDo = 3
while (tasksToDo > 0) {
    if (tasksToDo == 2) {
        continue;
    }
    console.log('there are ' + tasksToDo + ' tasks');
    tasksToDo--;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`conitnue`, will go back to the while loop. and tasksToDo will never get decremented further than 2.

```
var tasksToDo = 3
while (tasksToDo > 0) {
if (tasksToDo == 2) {
 tasksToDo--;             // Should be here too.
 continue;
}

console.log('there are ' + tasksToDo + ' tasks');
tasksToDo--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`continue` causes the loop to skip the decrement and begin all over again. Once `tasksToDo` hits 2, it stays 2 forever.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` makes you go back to the beginning of the loop. You probably wanted to use `break` instead.

Or maybe make your decrement *before* the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you're doing but from what I understand, you're trying to avoid executing logic inside while for `tasksToDo = 2`

```
var tasksToDo = 3
while (tasksToDo > 0) {
    if (tasksToDo != 2) {
        console.log('there are ' + tasksToDo + ' tasks');
    }
    tasksToDo--;
}
```

It wouldn't make sense to add a break in case `tasksToDo = 2` since it would be easier to add that condition to the while (`tasksToDo > 2`).

Code here might be totally different to your real code though so I could be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

you are using `continue;` that continue your loop forever
use  `break;` to exit instead of `continue;`

Answer (score 0):

Should it be like this?

```
var tasksToDo = 3
while (tasksToDo > 0) {
if (tasksToDo == 2) {
 continue;
 console.log('there are ' + tasksToDo + ' tasks');
 }
tasksToDo--;
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the code I was given to work with but I think i see whats going on thanks to some of the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

The "continue;" statement prevent the execution of all remaining declarations in the code block.

Therefore the "tasksDo--" decrement is not executed after the loop reaches "i == 2" any more.

This creates an infinite loop!

use the "for" loop instead

### the "for" loop solution for this case

```
var tasksToDo;

for (tasksToDo = 3; tasksToDo > 0; tasksToDo--){
    if (tasksToDo == 2) { continue; }
    console.log('there are ' + tasksToDo + ' tasks');
}
```

(the for loop accepts the decrement as its 3rd statement!)

Comment: You should also suggest how to solve this issue by reversing some lines of the code