# Infinite While loop mod 3

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I basically just want to print numbers a list of numbers a skip multiples of 3. I got it to work but the initial way i tried it did not work and i do not understand why, just need someone to please explain why it doesn't work and goes into an infinite loop.

This is the problem, why does it go into an infinite loop? I am clearly missing a key concept about code, if someone could help thanks.

```
var i = 0;
     while (i <= 10) {
         if (i % 3 == 0) {
            continue;
        }


       document.write( i + "</br>");
         i++;
        }
```

I know you can do it this way.

```
while (i <= 10) 
{

     if (i % 3 != 0) {

        document.write("Number is " + i + "<br />");  

    }

   i++

 }
```

Comment: Please try some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the first piece of code. Pay close attention to when and where you modify `i`.

Comment: I think this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403444/javascript-continue-statement-in-while-loop-causes-an-infinite-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ignore the code producing the output and look only at the code checking and modifying `i`, it might become a little more clear why it's not working. It also helps to [format our code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/127916/1541563) for extra clarity.

```
var i = 0;

while (i <= 10) {
  if (i % 3 == 0) {
    continue;
  }

  i++;
}
```

- Start with `i = 0`.
- `i <= 10` is `true`. Enter the loop.
- `i % 3 == 0` is `true`. Enter the `if` block.
- [`continue;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue). Go straight to the top of the `while` loop again. Do not pass `i++;`. Do not collect `1`.
- Lather. Rinse. Repeat (infinitely).

Comment: Thank you, i assumed continue meant carry on to the next line and Break meant go back to the top of the loop?

Comment: for(var i = 0; i <= 10; i ++){
            if(i % 3 == 0){
                continue;
            }
            document.write(i + "</br>");
       }

Comment: in the situation above it dose not go back to the top of the for loop, it still does the document.write? so it still completes the loop, so why for a while loop does it not complete the loop? I am not trying to argue just trying to understand. Thank you

Comment: @Mathew it _does_ go to the top of the loop, and lo and behold! There's an `i++` up there. [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) just exits the loop.

Comment: @Mathew `continue` skips the rest of the current iteration and starts the next. `break` breaks out of the loop, effectively ending it.

Answer (score 1):

`continue` jumps to the next iteration and doesnt complete the rest of your code in the `while`. So `i` is not being incremented but rather staying as 0 becuase you wrote `continue` before incrementing the `i`. so therefore it is in an endless loop, it is always less than 10